# Function parameter to pass different structures

Tags: c, function, struct, parameters

Is it possible to write a function, which

1. Can receive different types of structures from the same parameter ( maybe `void*` ?), and
2. Detects the type of the structure received in the function?

That is, when I call this function, I send a particular structure to it and when I call it again, I send a different type of structure.

Is this possible in C?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short anwer: No. Long answer: There are workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-fashioned way to do this is to have some generic struct containing an enum and a void pointer like:

```
typedef enum
{
  FOO_TYPE,
  BAR_TYPE
} type_t;

typedef struct {
  type_t type;
  void*  data;
} foo_t
```

You then inspect the enum `type` and cast the data pointer to the appropriate type.

In modern standard C, you can alternatively create type-generic, type safe macros like this:

```
void func_int   (int x);
void func_float (float x);

#define func(x) _Generic((x), case int: func_int, case float: func_float) (x)

...

int i;
float f;
func(i);
func(f);
```